# displaying posts with if post_meta is equal to current day

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

I start coding live soccer stream website with wordpress. I want do display my todays stream (posts) on my home page. I wrote **the loop like this**;

```
  <?php 

                    $dateget = trim(get_post_meta($post->ID,"Poz_Poz_Date",true));
                    $dateparse = explode(".",$dateget);
                    $current_day = date('j');

                        if ($dateparse[0] == $current_day) {
                            query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&meta_key=Poz_Poz_Timer&orderby=meta_value&order=asc&day='.$dateparse[0]);
                        } else {

                            query_posts('posts_per_page=0&day='.$dateparse[0]);
                        }


                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

**The Custom Posts meta are;**

- For Event Time : Poz_Poz_Timer ( Format : hh:mm)

  For Evet Date : Poz_Poz_Date ( Format : dd.mm.yy)

I want to display only todays posts, order by event date ASC with this query

This loop currently doesnt work. What should i do ?